# Anticipation of there is/there are

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, verb-agreement

Please tell me, why can I not use There is and There are in the way I feel it based on my anticipation of the items listed?

What is wrong with saying:

- There are a box of chocolates and a couple of bottles of wine on this table.
- There are a cat, a dog and two birds in this picture.

What if all the objects in the list are perceived as a single plural object?

Doesn't English grammar allow me to render whichever list as a mass?

Comment: English grammar dictates that your subject agree with your verb in number. In your first sentence *there* refers to a box, which is a single thing no matter many sweeties it contains. Therefore you have to say "There is." In your second sentence the subject is a conjunction of animal names, which is plural, so "There are" is fine.

Comment: @user105719 But I see fit to render "a box of chocolates" and "a couple of bottles of wine" as a plural compound object. For me it is a one plural noun like "a couple" or "a dozen"

Comment: English grammar is a set of rules for a standard version of the language. Not everybody agrees on those rules, and not everybody abides by them. The former because the language is complicated; the latter because not everybody speaks or writes standard English. That said, the grammar rules don't care what you see fit to render. According to definitions that help describe the language, *A couple* means two, and that's plural. *A box* is singular. Descriptive rules are not prescriptive, i.e, they neither allow nor prohibit. The only penalty for violations is that you speak or write incorrectly.

Comment: @user105719 In this case many regions in England and many Americans and very many English native-speakers write and speak incorrectly. Some use a singular verb after I, some use "was" instead if "were" in the subjunctive, some say "a series" is plural whereas others say it's singular.

Comment: Absolutely correct. In fact, many American native speakers write and (especially) speak using two different sets of rules, one for formal occasions (say, at a job interview) and one for informal occasions (say, talking with friends and family). That's why it's important to make clear against which version of the language one applies judgments of correctness. Some rules cannot be violated in the sense that violations lead to gibberish in all versions of the language. Others can be broken in all versions (e.g., some uses of the subjunctive mood). And, of course, there are in between cases.

Comment: @user105719 I don't agree at all. How is _a box and two bottles_ different from _a cat and two birds_?

Comment: Thank you, @KateBunting. I'm sorry, OP. I misread your sentence. Of course, now I don't understand your question. Your first sentence has three things governing the verb: 1 box and 2 bottles. So the verb should be the plural *are*.  If you have a list (implying multiple elements) as a subject, the verb must be plural. You don't have to do an analysis of making the list a single plural thing (whatever that means); it's already plural. Which do you choose for "There **is/was** a box of chocolates on the table"?

Comment: Again, thanks @KateBunting. The answer to your question is that a cat will jump in a box, and bottles can't fly.

Comment: Some speakers would apply the concept of 'proximity' here, whereby the verb agrees with the nearest noun in the coordination of NPs. In your first example, the nearest NP is the singular "a box of chocolates", so we'd expect to find singular "is". On the other hand, in "There is/are two birds, a dog and a cat", the nearest NP is the plural "two birds", so we'd expect to find the plural verb "are".

Comment: @BillJ I wouldn't expect to see _is_ in the first sentence. Both the OP's sentences refer to several objects/animals and, to me, are perfectly fine. Anyway, the two birds are mentioned last!

Comment: I was trying (and failed!) to say that if we reverse the order of the NPs in the OP's second example, the plural "two birds" is nearest to the verb. I can't see anything wrong with "is" in the first example, especially with reduced "is", as in "There's a box of chocolates and a couple of bottles of wine on this table". Likewise in "There's a cat, a dog and two birds in this picture".